# How can I assign a variable to an ID in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, background

I am trying to make a background for my website using javascript and I need to know how to assign the variable I have made to a part of my page that has an ID. Currently, the background shows underneath all the content so I need to assign it to a div that has an ID.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks

```
<div id="background"></div>

const pattern = trianglify({
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  cellSize: 75,
  xColors: 'Blues',
  yColors: 'match',
  variance: 0.75,
})

document.getElementById('background').appendChild(pattern.toCanvas())
```

Comment: Your code works. Are you including [the script after the HTML markup/deferring its loading until the DOM has loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What does "assign a variable" mean? What problem are you facing? See [ask] for tips.